# PHP - merge values from array with same key and different values

Tags: php, foreach

I've got the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => something [1] => anotherhing )
```

What i want to obtain is :

```
Array ( [0] => [something, anotherthing] )
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have `$original_arr = ['something', 'anotherthing']` and you want a new array that has this array as value in first position, simply do `$new_arr = [$original_arr]`. This assumes all involved arrays are non-associative, which seems to be the case according to your question.

However, if your goal is the have an array whose first value is a string composed from the entries of the first array, do this:

```php
$str = '[';
$str .= implode(', ', $original_arr);
$str .= ']';
$new_arr = [$str];
```

Updated solution with `implode`, thanks to @Jon.

Comment: This is reimplementing `implode`, there's no need for that.